# What does the "install" function mean in C syntax?

Tags: c, r, function, syntax

I'm trying to understand the C code called by the R package ucminf.  The following code is from the file interface.c found at https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ucminf_1.1-4.tar.gz:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>  //R internal structures
#include <R_ext/RS.h>    //F77_CALL etc.

// Declare FORTRAN routine for use in C
extern void F77_NAME(ucminf)(int*, double[], double*, double[],
                 int*,double[],int*,int*,int*,double[],SEXP);

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Define C functions that calls user defined function in R
*/

void installPar(int nn, double x[], SEXP rho) {
    int i;
    SEXP PAR = findVarInFrame(rho, install(".x"));
    double *xpt = REAL(PAR);
    if (LENGTH(PAR) != nn)
    error("Dimension mismatch, length(.x) = %d != n = $d", LENGTH(PAR), nn);
    for (i = 0; i < nn; i++) xpt[i] = x[i] ;
}
```

`rho` is an environment created in R, and it contains the vector `.x`.  My best guess is that the line `SEXP PAR = findVarInFrame(rho, install(".x"));` is setting `PAR` equal to `.x`, but what does the `install()` command do?

This is such a simple question that I was surprised I couldn't find the answer online - searching for "install c syntax" turned up lots of information about how to install compilers, but I couldn't find anything about the command.  Any suggestions for keywords to make my searches more effective would be appreciated.

Comment: C does not have "commands", although it can pass them to the OS you are using.

Comment: Try `man install` ...

Comment: @WeatherVane OK - is 'function' the correct term?  I'll edit the question to use the right terminology

Comment: @l'L'l "DESCRIPTION
       This  install  program copies files (often just compiled) into destination locations you choose...."
       Does `install(".x")` pass ".x" to the OS's install command?

Comment: @beandip: In your case it's more specific to `R` and the meaning is not the same ( see Andrew's answer ).

Comment: @downvoter: what do you suggest I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is part of an R extension I think, and therefore the use of `install` here is a function call to the R C API for [Writing Extension](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).  What this does is create the symbol `.x` in the current symbol table (or return a reference to the existing `.x` symbol).  The linked document does indicate that using `install` is harmless if the symbol already exists, and is a good way of looking up the symbol if that's what you actually want to do.